# How to apply Elliott wave priciple to any Time Series?

Tags: time-series

I'm strongly interested to computing Elliott Wave to any given Timeseries. Does anybody tried?

Is there any phython library to do that?

I'm looking for an algorithm taht if I give to it a time series, it label each movement according to [Elliott Wave principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliott_wave_principle).

Comment: Elliot wave principle seems pretty informal to me. What exactly do you want to compute? Perhaps you can extend your question?

Comment: @werediver I would to label automatically each movement (aka wave) and plot it

Comment: All automated EW counters have huge problem.when it recounts it does not calculate the losses.so better not to use any without backtesting it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's C++

http://ewavetrade.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ewavetrade/ElliotEngine/ewave_lib.cpp?revision=1.13&view=markup3

Here's MQL5

https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/260 or https://www.mql5.com/en/code/10582

I'm very interested in python implementation as well.

Also, [TradingView](https://www.tradingview.com/) automatically marks up Elliot waves on their charts.   The source pinescript is black box though.

The markup is certainly not: "Elliot wave principle seems pretty informal to me"

Comment: I deleted you second answer and merged it with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Have not seen any Python libraries for that strangely. I have a feeling you wont find any. Fibonacci Numbers are easy to calculate in Python.

Comment: Yes, Fibonacci is the easiest part. The hard part is the visual labelling of movements